# Python Shopping Cart with only outer while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, shopping-cart

I'm new to python and programming in general.
I'm starting with my first mini project, a shopping cart.

I have everything working but I have been told I could get the whole loop going with just the outer one and that I do not require the second one. I've been wracking my brain all day trying to see how to get it to work, to no avail. Some pointers of how it can be achieved would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

```
shopping_list = []
print("Hi, Welcome to Jolly's Market.")
while True:
    customer = input("To add to the shopping cart, press 1. To checkout and leave press 2.\n")


    if customer == "1":
        print("To return to the menu, type exit . To remove items, type r")
        while customer != "exit" or customer != "r":
            shopping_list.append(input("Add to cart: "))
            print(shopping_list)
            customer = input("").lower()

            if customer == "exit":
                print("Sending you back to the menu")
                break
                

            if customer == "r":
                shopping_list.pop(int(input("Remove item ")))  
                print(shopping_list)
                shopping_list.append(input("Add to cart: "))
                print(shopping_list)
                customer = input("").lower()
            
            if len(shopping_list) == 10:
                print("You have ten items, do you wish to add more? (y, n)")
                customer = input(" ").lower()
            
            if customer == "y":
                shopping_list.append(input("Add to cart: "))
            elif customer == "n":
                print("Sending you back to the main menu")
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

The inner while loop is not required because it can be done with only the outer while loop.

Here's how you can modify the code:

```py
shopping_list = []
print("Hi, Welcome to Jolly's Market.")
while True:
    customer = input("To add to the shopping cart, press 1. To checkout and leave press 2.\n")

    if customer == "1":
        print("To return to the menu, type exit . To remove items, type r")
        item = input("Add to cart: ")
        shopping_list.append(item)
        print(shopping_list)
        customer = input("").lower()

        if customer == "exit":
            print("Sending you back to the menu")
            continue

        if customer == "r":
            shopping_list.pop(int(input("Remove item ")))  
            print(shopping_list)
            item = input("Add to cart: ")
            shopping_list.append(item)
            print(shopping_list)
            customer = input("").lower()
        
        if len(shopping_list) == 10:
            print("You have ten items, do you wish to add more? (y, n)")
            customer = input(" ").lower()
        
        if customer == "y":
            item = input("Add to cart: ")
            shopping_list.append(item)
        elif customer == "n":
            print("Sending you back to the main menu")
            continue 
    elif customer == "2":
        break
```

Here, the inner while loop is not required because the menu options are already in the outer loop. When the user types `1`, the shopping list is updated, and then the user is asked to either add or remove items. If the length of the shopping list reaches 10, the user is asked if they want to add more. If the user types `exit` or `n`, they are sent back to the main menu. If the user types `2`, the while loop breaks and the program ends.

Comment: Yeah, I get that, what I'm trying to avoid is being taken back to the menu every time after placing a new item on the list. With the two loops I was able to continuously add items until the user decides to quit either before 10 items or at 10. Thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 0):

Here's a revised version of the code that will let you continuously add items to the shopping list without being taken back to the main menu after each item, until you reach 10 items or decide to exit:

```py
shopping_list = []
print("Hi, Welcome to Jolly's Market.")
while True:
    customer = input("To add to the shopping cart, press 1. To checkout and leave press 2.\n")

    if customer == "1":
        print("To return to the menu, type exit . To remove items, type r")
        while True:
            item = input("Add to cart: ")
            shopping_list.append(item)
            print(shopping_list)
            
            if len(shopping_list) == 10:
                print("You have ten items, do you wish to add more? (y, n)")
                customer = input(" ").lower()
                if customer == "n":
                    break
                else:
                    continue
            
            customer = input("").lower()
            
            if customer == "exit":
                print("Sending you back to the menu")
                break
            
            if customer == "r":
                shopping_list.pop(int(input("Remove item ")))  
                print(shopping_list)
        continue
    elif customer == "2":
        break
```